# A redis INFO: -ERR wrong number of arguments for 'info' command

Tags: redis

so i just ran INFO command as described here http://redis.io/commands/info

but it gives me only default sections - like cpu info and other

and when i try to add `[section]` parameter - it goes wrong:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 6379
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.

INFO keyspace
-ERR wrong number of arguments for 'info' command

INFO all
-ERR wrong number of arguments for 'info' command
```

so how do i get keyspace section of INFO command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It occurs that `info section` isn't working in redis versions <2.6.

So I end up using simple `info` without section parameter, though it won't give you all.

Comment: But that's exactly what I told you on Feb' 10th :(

Comment: Put differently - why didn't you accept my answer (or respond to it for that matter)?

Comment: I couldn't vote for the comment you left, because SO allows to "accept" only if it's posted as "answer". And because you never bothered to update your post so as it would contain an actual answer, I figured that I can answer my own question.

Answer (score 2):

No issues here doing info [section] via telnet or redis-cli:

```
$ telnet localhost 6379
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
info keyspace
$34
# Keyspace
db0:keys=5,expires=0

quit
+OK
Connection closed by foreign host.
$ redis-cli
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> info keyspace
# Keyspace
db0:keys=5,expires=0
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> quit
$ redis-server --version
Redis server v=2.6.13 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-3.3.1 bits=64
```

What version of Redis are you using ?

Comment: info
    $902
    redis_version:2.2.12

Comment: See line 68 in https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/00-RELEASENOTES -> looks like the INFO [SUBSECTION] functionality is an addition from 2.6